# Find file and if exist do nothing with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have list of files:

```
root@server:/etc/apt/apt.conf.d# ll
total 68
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr  4 15:15 ./
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Mar 25 14:44 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  630 Apr  9  2020 01autoremove
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 1677 Apr  4 14:09 01autoremove-kernels
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   92 Apr  9  2020 01-vendor-ubuntu
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  129 May 14  2021 10periodic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  108 May 14  2021 15update-stamp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  604 Jan 20 21:02 20apt-esm-hook.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   85 May 14  2021 20archive
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   80 Jul 21  2020 20auto-upgrades
```

**I want to find a file with mask** `**periodic` (because numbers can be different), **then if exist, nothink to do, if does not exist create file** `02periodic`

I have task:

```yaml
- name : Find files
  find:
    paths: /etc/apt/apt.conf.d
    file_type: file
    patterns: 
      - '[0-9]periodic'
    use_regex: yes
  register: output
    
- name: Create file if it doesn't exists
  file:
    path: "/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02periodic"
    state: touch
  when: output == False

- name: Add configuration to file "02periodic"
  copy:
    dest: "/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02periodic"
    content: |
      APT::Periodic::Enable "1";
      APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
```

But it does not work. Could you please help? What I should to do for this?

Comment: `output == False` will never be true; please use `- debug: var=output` to show what the contents are, or [use the fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html#return-values)

Comment: `[0-9]periodic` will not match your any of your existing file example since they all start with 2 digits. If you are not too paranoid, use `[0-9]*periodic`. To be more conservative you can use `[0-9]{2}periodic`. This is actually the next problem you will face after fixing the one reported in the above comment.

Comment: Although @Zeitounator comments is part of your issue, all of this is not even needed, doing a `touch` of a file (either in a command or in Ansible) will create a file if it does not exists and do nothing if it does exists already. That's part of Asnible idempotency mechanism playing here.

Comment: And this is actually stated in the manual, too: [_If `touch` (new in 1.4), an empty file will be created if the file does not exist, while an existing file or directory will receive updated file access and modification times (similar to the way `touch` works from the command line)._](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html#parameter-state)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε you simply missed that OP wants to check for `??periodic` (whatever the digits are) and create `02periodic` if no file exist with that pattern. This is out of classic copy/template idem-potency.

Comment: @Zeitounator Will `[0-9]*periodic` also match `periodic`, with no preceding number?

Comment: @jack: [help yourself](https://regex101.com/r/sVQKNT/1)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much my friends,

I created tasks using yours help. I think have other solutions, more short, but at this moment I do not know about this solution :0)

```
- name: Ansible find files in folder /etc/apt/apt.conf.d using Python regex
  find:
    paths: /etc/apt/apt.conf.d
    patterns: "[0-9]{2}periodic"
    recurse: yes
    use_regex: yes
  register: register_name

- name: Output if files is NOT exist
  debug:
    msg: "The file is NOT exist with name **periodic THEN we are creating the new file with name 02periodic"
  when: register_name.matched == 0

- name: Touch the file 02periodic if files **periodic does NOT exists
  copy:
    dest: /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02periodic
    content: |
      APT::Periodic::Enable "1";
      APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
  when: register_name.matched == 0

- name: Output if files with names **periodic exists
  debug:
    msg: "The file with name **periodic EXIST"
  when: register_name.matched >= 0
```

**Output:**

```
root@hcloud-admin:/etc/ansible/playbooks# ansible-playbook -v init_update_zabbix.yaml
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file

PLAY [SERVER] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [SERVER]

TASK [/etc/ansible/roles/update_zabbix : Ansible find files in folder /etc/apt/apt.conf.d using Python regex] *******************************************************************************************
ok: [SERVER] => {"changed": false, "examined": 14, "files": [], "matched": 0, "msg": "All paths examined", "skipped_paths": {}}

TASK [/etc/ansible/roles/update_zabbix : Output if files is NOT exist] **********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [SERVER] => {
    "msg": "The file is NOT exist with name **periodic THEN we are creating the new file with name 02periodic"
}

TASK [/etc/ansible/roles/update_zabbix : Touch the file 02periodic if files **periodic does NOT exists] *************************************************************************************************
changed: [SERVER] => {"changed": true, "checksum": "a945d7a498d6c699b13deb02885ecac463085c7a", "dest": "/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02periodic", "gid": 0, "group": "root", "md5sum": "7630fcbb5626746a19f3d71e2e8910ef", "mode": "0644", "owner": "root", "size": 68, "src": "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1649145453.3007545-1415999-121396802409963/source", "state": "file", "uid": 0}

TASK [/etc/ansible/roles/update_zabbix : Output if files with names **periodic exists] ******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [SERVER] => {
    "msg": "The file with name **periodic EXIST"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
SERVER                     : ok=5    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```